What are cylinder objects in the category of simplicial sets?
I think the projection $X\times\Delta^1\to X$ is a cylinder object in sSet the category of simplicial sets (with the Quillen model structure), since $|X\times \Delta^1|\cong |X|\times_k [0,1]\to |X|$ is a weak equivalence.
But if so, the simplicial homotopy is the left homotopy, and always an equivalence relation since all objects in sSet are cofibrant (c.f. Mark Hovey, Model categories, Proposition 1.2.5). However, the simplicial homotopy is not an equivalence relation on ${\bf sSet}(X,Y)$ when $Y$ is not fibrant.
So what is wrong with the above 'contradiction'? If $X\times\Delta^1\to X$ is not a cyliner object, what is a cylinder object over $X$?

The mistake is 'the simplicial homotopy is the left homotopy'. $f$ is simpicially homotopic to $g$ (denoted by $f\sim_s g$) implies $f\sim
_l g$ but the converse may be not true, so the simplicial homotopy need not be an equivalence relation. In fact the left homotopy is automatically a symmetric relation because we can interchange the names of $d^i$'s in the cofibration $d^0+d^1:X\coprod X\to{\rm Cyl}(X)$. But when we say $f\sim_s g$, corresponding $d^i$'s are induced by definite maps $\Delta^0\to \Delta^1$.
